# How to avoid Global Scope documentation generated by JSDoc on NodeJS functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, jsdoc

JSdoc generated documentation on my nodejs modules.

```
/**
 Do something
*/
function doSomething(param1, param2) {
  // blah blah
  ...
}

module.exports.doSomething = doSomething;
```

JSDoc's generated file generated the comment under Global scope, and I have hundreds of exported functions like that.

Is there any way to make JSDoc to generated the documentations grouped by module file names?

Comment: Answering my own question. JSDoc has @module tag to address the exported function and class in nodejs that uses CommonJS.  http://usejsdoc.org/howto-commonjs-modules.html

But it seems cumbersome. If anyone knows a better solution, please let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

At the top of your file, you need to include a jsdoc comment like so.  You can also name the module to something else if desired.

```
/**
 @module FileNameOrCustomModuleName
*/
```

I don't think you can have multiple `@module` directives in a single file though.